# Document Library Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column

I have a document library in which are a couple thousand image files formatted as such:

**CQYr UnqID   Title      FNme  LNme   Agency**

2020 RR0000 Bus Driver Roger Rabbit Federal

I am trying to create several calculated columns in the SP library for filtering purposes. Yep, I've been told that I may not be able to filter using calculated columns; my focus is on the calculation at this point; why is it not working?.

My first attempt was to extract the CQYr from the Title using the following. The result in the calculated column is #Name?.

Any thoughts?

=LEFT(Title,(FIND(" ",Title)-1))

Answer (score 0):

I used your formula **as-is**, but could not reproduce the error in SharePoint 2013.
In your environment, it seems FIND() for a **space** char is returning error. You can use ISERROR() with IF statement to further troubleshoot.

```
As-is formula worked for me in SP2013
=LEFT(Title,(FIND(" ",Title)-1))

Use the below to see why FIND() is not successful in your case.
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(" ",Title))),LEFT(Title,(FIND(" ",Title)-1)),"Not Found")
```

[image]

Comment: All came back 'Not Found'.

Comment: That means it's not finding the space char. In your formula, can you replace the space char with "R" or "B" or "D" etc like FIND("B", Title) to see what the output is?

Comment: Using your suggestion, rather than adding letters I simply moved the emphasis. Now the conditions says - =LEFT(Title,(FIND("J",Title)-1)). The first item in the list has a Title of 2020JJ1234. Based on the condition the return should be 2020, yes? Its not; still returns #Value!

Comment: Let's try another example, update your formula to  =LEFT("2020JJ1234",(FIND("J","2020JJ1234")-1)) . Try finding value in string "2020JJ1234", see how it works.

Comment: I cut and paste this from you comments into the calculation: =LEFT("2020JJ1234" (FIND("J","2020JJ1234")-1)) . The CQYears go from 1987 - 2020. The change you suggested made all lines show the content of "2020" in the CQYear column, regardless of the CQYr in the file names.

Comment: That's is the expected output for all items because **search within text** is hard-coded in the formula and is the same for all rows/items. Now, I have to ask see if [Title] column used in the formula has correct values? If it does, it should return the correct output. Please verify your column name and update your formula accordingly.

Comment: I  checked and re-checked both the name of the column in the view and in 'Library Setting'; it is "Title". The conditions is currently: =LEFT(Title,(FIND("J",Title)-1)) ; The first line item is: 1987 JZ0000 Firefighter I John Zoom ; the result in the CQYear column should be "1987", yes? It is not; the result is "#Value!" BTW, all of these files are conversions to .jpg from .pdf. I did them myself. I also manually deleted and overwrote the first file name, to try to address the space issue. Same result #Value!

Comment: I figured it out! I went to the file name 'details'. In there no file name exists in the 'Title' line, only in the "Name" line. Once I cut and paste the actual file name into the 'Title' field in 'details' the condition worked. Question now is, why doesn't the file name auto-populate into the 'Title' field when the file was uploaded to the Library? And, how do I now add 2,700 'Title' entries after the fact?

Comment: [Title] column doesn't get automatically populated with values from File [Name] column unless you use some workflow or some other means to populate it. But, I'm wondering, why you can't use the file [Name] column to extract the desire text as you would from the [Title].

Comment: Please let me know what your wondering reveals, post epiphany. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116860/discussion-between-curtis-and-matiur-rahman).

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you are not referring to the correct column, as [Matiur Rahman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287385/document-library-calculated-column/Comment#comment305319_287389) mentioned. If you can return “Not Found” for all columns, it suggests that the formula is working fine.

Change the field name in your formula and see the result.

Example:

[image]

The formula I test with:

```
=LEFT([Filename sample],(FIND(" ",[Filename sample])-1))
```

Comment: The only applicable 'field' name revealed to me by SP in the making of the calculated column IS "Title"; even though there is no data in "Title". The data is in the 'Name' column of the view; however, when I go to Library setting "Name" in not a column option - only "Title". If I manually update the "Title" field in properties through 'See Details' the formula fine. No of it makes sense.

Comment: @Curtis The Name field created by default is `Name (linked to document with edit menu)` and cannot be used in Calculated Column formula.
Actually, that would be the default behavior for all Office documents. If you check the properties for the files on local drive or in Office clients (not in SharePoint libraries), you will find the `Title` field empty, which is part of word properties. But your file needs a filename to be able to save, which would be the value of `Name` field. That is why the Title field can be left empty in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I went to the file name 'details'. In there no file name exists in the 'Title' line, only in the "Name" line. Once I cut and paste the actual file name into the 'Title' field in 'details' the condition worked.

[image]